# LibreOffice Writer - Create and apply table style

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have a bunch of tables in a Writer document that I would like to style in the same way. I selected a table, then opened "Table Properties" and modified the borders and background colors.

Then, with the same table selected, I opened "Table -> Autoformat Styles", clicked "Add" and inserted the name. Unfortunately, the newly created style is precisely identical to "Default Style": my colors and borders properties where not included.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: LibreOffice 6.3.5.2 30(Build:2)

Comment: Using 6.4.4.2 here. I followed what you did, and the newly created style was added with the modifications I made. I think you should update your version.

Comment: Hello @ReddyLutonadio , I've updated to LibreOffice 6.4.5.2. Repeating the procedure, the border styles and fonts styles are applied, but not background colors...

Comment: Can you try to repeat the steps on a new document?

Comment: I tried, same result!

Comment: I recorded the [steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9B8H.gif) I followed.  Are there any differences between what I did, and your steps?

Comment: That's precisely how I did it. I have also tried the same procedure in safe mode, no luck. Only border styles are applied. BTW, I purged the previous installation...

Comment: That's strange behavior on your side. Maybe other forum users will come up with other ideas on how to solve this issue.